# Boost serialization for some attributes of the class

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have this class that I want to serialize/deserialize it using boost.

```
class T{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
    T() = default;
    ~T() = default;
    template<class Archive> inline void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version){
        ar & b;
        ar & c;
    }

    int a;
    float b;
    float c;
    std::vector<int> d;
};
```

Is there any problem that I am just serializing b,c?  should I do any further steps to tell that I am not serializing the whole class?

Comment: No and no. It's fine to do it this way.

Comment: Just make sure default-constructed `T` has some sane state.